# Most efficient way to combine several dataframes with complementary missing values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is probably a pretty basic question. Suppose I have two dataframes:

```
>>> df1
   id     a
0   0   5.0
1   1  10.0
2   2  15.0
3   3   NaN
4   4   NaN
5   5   NaN

>>> df2
   id     a
0   0   NaN
1   1   NaN
2   2   NaN
3   3  20.0
4   4  25.0
5   5  30.0
```

I want to join the dataframes on `id` to look like:

```
>>> df_joined
   id     a
0   0   5.0
1   1  10.0
2   2  15.0
3   3  20.0
4   4  25.0
5   5  30.0
```

So far, I have been doing left merges, e.g. `df1.merge(df2, how = 'left', on = 'id)` but this results in duplicated columns (see below) that I have to correct by filling the nans, renaming the columns, and then dropping the duplicate. This becomes particularly tedious if I have more than 2 dataframes to merge.

```
# How do I better merge this so I don't have fill nans, rename, and drop the columns?
   id   a_x   a_y
0   0   5.0   NaN
1   1  10.0   NaN
2   2  15.0   NaN
3   3   NaN  20.0
4   4   NaN  25.0
5   5   NaN  30.0
```

What's a better way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC, [`DataFrame.combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html)

```
df1.combine_first(df2)

   id     a
0   0   5.0
1   1  10.0
2   2  15.0
3   3  20.0
4   4  25.0
5   5  30.0
```

**EDIT**

We can use [`DataFrame.set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) + [`DataFrame.combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with `map` and `reduce` for **n** DataFrames.

```
my_list_df = [df1, df2]

from functools import reduce
reduce(lambda new_df,  df_to_combine: new_df.combine_first(df_to_combine), 
       map(lambda df: df.set_index('id'), my_list_df)).reset_index()
```

**Output**

```
   id     a
0   0   5.0
1   1  10.0
2   2  15.0
3   3  20.0
4   4  25.0
5   5  30.0
```

In this case we only need `reduce`:

```
reduce(lambda new_df, df_to_combine: new_df.combine_first(df_to_combine.set_index('id')),
       my_list_df[1:], my_list_df[0].set_index('id')).reset_index()
```

Comment: I think `combine_first` is position based but the OP talked about based on column `id` to fill the column a, here it works because the id column and the index are the same and both dataframes ordered the same way?

Comment: Thanks @Ben.T - good points. Let me clarify we can assume all dataframes are ordered the same. In that case, it looks like ```combine_first``` works even if ```id``` is not the same as the index. If they are not ordered the same, then it does not work

Comment: @jetvermillion yes if they are ordered the same way with same index, then combine_first is a good solution